# Why is my font not always Fira Sans using XeLaTeX?

Tags: fonts, xetex

I'd like to use Fira Sans as the main font because it has awesome math support, but I'd like to use other fonts as well, which is why I'd like to use XeLaTeX with the fontspec package. However, it appears to change the font here and there and I don't know why.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{FiraSans}
\usepackage{newtxsf}

\begin{document}

Writing numbers 12345 in line and in $12345$ math mode using the font Fira Sans.\\

Some math:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^4 a_0 q^k
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Using LaTeX:
[image]

Using XeLaTeX:
[image]

Comment: never use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` with xetex, that is forcing legacy 8bit fonts so negating most benefis of xetex which is designed for Unicode opentype fonts. It will also cause incorrect hyphenation (probably not in English, but in any language using accented letters)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle interesting, I didn't know about this stuff, good to know

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On XeTeX, the `Firasans` package loads `fontspec`, which sets up the `\mathrm` font in a way that breaks with `sfdefault`.  This is a bug in the `FiraSans` package.

One solution is to use modern OpenType fonts with `fontsetup` (which loads Fira Math in `unicode-math`):

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[fira]{fontsetup}

\begin{document}

Writing numbers 12345 in line and in $12345$ math mode using the font Fira Sans.\\

Some math:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^4 a_0 q^k
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image: Fira Math sample]

I recommend you use OpenType fonts when you can, and legacy 8-bit packages when you have to.

If you want to use your legacy math font with Fira Sans, you can turn off the redefinition of `\mathrm`, which is used as the operator font for `\lim`, in `fontspec` before you load `FiraSans`:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\PassOptionsToPackage{no-math}{fontspec}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{FiraSans}
\usepackage{newtxsf}

\begin{document}

Writing numbers 12345 in line and in $12345$ math mode using the font Fira Sans.\\

Some math:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^4 a_0 q^k
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image: Fira Sans + newtxsf sample]

You could also fix `\mathrm` afterwards with `\setmathrm`, as `\usepackage[sfdefault]{FiraSans]` should have done.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[sfdefault]{FiraSans}
\setmathrm{Fira Sans}
\usepackage{newtxsf}

\begin{document}

Writing numbers 12345 in line and in $12345$ math mode using the font Fira Sans.\\

Some math:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^4 a_0 q^k
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image: Fira Sans + newtxsf sample]

Comment: Thanks, the first suggestion works perfectly, the other two still have a bit of that non-matching serif in the math bit, but it's still informative!

Comment: @Steven That’s because they use the legacy `newtxsf` package for math, like in your example. If you don’t want to use `unicode-math`, you could pick a different legacy package that you feel matches better.